# Find min and max of n-tuple?

Tags: c#, f#

I have a tuple representing x-y coordinates. These tuples are then used to define the sizes of two boxes as seen here[image: here]. Then I would like to create a bounding box surrounding these two boxes  which then has the two points; one for the bottom left and one for the top right. The bot-right point would have the x-coordinate min(p1.x, p3.x), y-coordinate = min(p1.y, p3.y). The top-right point would have x=max(p2.x, p4.x), y=max(p2.y, p4.y) if I am not mistaken.

The main problem that I have to is to find a way to get the min and max of n-tuples and derive these two new points for the outer bounding box in a rather pretty way.

Comment: sounds suspiciously like a homework problem

Comment: Well, it is for an openGL project that I am working on

Comment: In C#, you use [Rectangle.Union()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.union) to have the sum of two rectangles. The union Rectangle have Bounds: `(Min(rect1.X, rect2.X), Min(rect1.Y, rect2.Y)), (Max(rect1.Right, rect2.Right), Max(rect1.Bottom, rect2.Bottom)))`. The tuple can then be extracted from the union rectangle Bounds, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to give a useful answer without knowing a bit more about the context and without seeing any sample code of what you have so far. However, your four points are presumably four tuples:

```
let p1 = (0, 5)
let p2 = (10, 15)
let p3 = (5, 0)
let p4 = (15, 10)
```

Now, if you just want to get the minimal X and Y values, you can create a list of all the points and use `minBy`:

```
let ps = [p1; p2; p3; p4] 
let minX = ps |> List.minBy fst
let minY = ps |> List.minBy snd
```

Comment: Perfect, but what if you had to find the min and max of just one n-tuple? Would you then convert it to a list containing all the elements in the n-tuple or how would you deal with that efficiently?

Comment: That looks like F# instead of C# ?

Comment: @NetMage The question had an F# tag when I answered it - now it seems to be back :-).

Comment: @ThatGuy I guess you would not often work with n-tuples. You might have a tuple of coordinates representing a rectangle and then a list of such rectangles. Converting them to a list sounds like a reasonable option to me.

Comment: Is there an F# equivalent of `Aggregate` so you could min and max in one pass?

Comment: @NetMage Sure there is an `Aggregate` in F#, for lists it's called [`List.fold`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.fold%5B%27t%2C%27state%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D). In code golf mode: `((p1,p1),[p2;p3;p4])||>List.fold(fun((l,b),(r,t))(x,y)->(min l x, min b y),(max r x,max t y))`

Answer (score 1):

In something similar to @TomasPetricek's answer, you can use LINQ in C#:

```
var p1 = (0, 5);
var p2 = (10, 15);
var p3 = (5, 0);
var p4 = (15, 10);

var ps = new[] { p1, p2, p3, p4 };

var minX = ps.Select(p => p.Item1).Min();
var minY = ps.Select(p => p.Item2).Min();
```

Abusing the LINQ `Aggregate` method, you can compute the answer at once:

```
var ps = new[] { p2, p3, p4 };

var ans = ps.Aggregate((p1, p1), (rect, p) => ((Math.Min(rect.Item1.Item1,p.Item1),Math.Min(rect.Item1.Item2,p.Item2)),
                                               (Math.Max(rect.Item2.Item1,p.Item1),Math.Max(rect.Item2.Item2,p.Item2))));
```